# django how to filter import_export file

Tags: python, django

How do i filter the CustomerSectionResource models? in my case all data save in the database export in the excel, I just want to select certain data to export in excel. i want to filter just like this

Ex.

```
company = FmCustomerUsers.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
obj = FmCustomerSection.objects.filter(
        fmCustomerID__company_name__in=company.values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name'))
```

how? help me guys....

resources.py

```
class FmCustomerSectionResource(resources.ModelResource):
    fmCustomerID = fields.Field(attribute='customer', column_name='customer',
                            widget=ForeignKeyWidget(FmCustomer))

    class Meta:
        model = FmCustomerSection
        fields = ('fmCustomerID', 'section', 'inputdate', 'inputBy', 'modifyDate', 'modifyBy', 'status')
```

views.py

```
from tablib import Dataset
from .resources import FmCustomerSectionResource
def import_Section(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_format = request.POST['file-format']
        company = FmCustomerUsers.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
        product_resource = FmCustomerSectionResource.objects.filter(
        fmCustomerID__company_name__in=company.values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name'))
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_city = request.FILES['importData']

        if file_format == 'XLS':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_city.read(), format='xls')
            result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)

        elif file_format == 'CSV':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_city.read(), format='csv')
            # Testing data import
            result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)

        if not result.has_errors():
            # Import now
            product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)

    return redirect('Section')

def export_Section(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get selected option from form
        file_format = request.POST['importData']
        product_resource = FmCustomerSectionResource()
        dataset = product_resource.export()
        if file_format == 'CSV':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.csv"'
            return response
        elif file_format == 'XLS':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.xls, content_type='application/xls')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.xls"'
            return response
    return redirect('Section')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tablib import Dataset
from .resources import FmCustomerSectionResource
def import_Section(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_format = request.POST['file-format']
        company = FmCustomerUsers.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
        product = FmCustomerSection.objects.filter(
     fmCustomerID__company_name__in=company.values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name'))
        product_resource = FmCustomerSectionResource()
        dataset = product_resource .exclude(product)
        new_city = request.FILES['importData']

        if file_format == 'XLS':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_city.read(), format='xls')
            result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)

        elif file_format == 'CSV':
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_city.read(), format='csv')
            # Testing data import
            result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)

        if not result.has_errors():
            # Import now
            product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)

    return redirect('Section')

def export_Section(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get selected option from form
        file_format = request.POST['importData']
        product_resource = FmCustomerSectionResource()
        dataset = product_resource.export()
        if file_format == 'CSV':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.csv"'
            return response
        elif file_format == 'XLS':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.xls, content_type='application/xls')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.xls"'
            return response
    return redirect('Section')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this question is almost identical to this one, [django-import-export how to skip import some rows based on current user login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712729/django-import-export-how-to-skip-import-some-rows-based-on-current-user-login)

> You can use the
> [**`skip_row(...)`**--(Doc)](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.skip_row)
> method, as you mentioned.
>
> But, the ***`skip_row(...)`*** method doesn't provide any hooks to the
> `request.user`, so, we are doing a *simple hack* to get the requested
> user in `skip_row()` by overriding the  ***`import_data(...)`***
>
> ```
> from import_export.resources import ModelResource
>
>
> class BookResource(ModelResource):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Book
>
>     def import_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.user = kwargs.get("user") # Here, we are assigning the requested user to the `ModelResource` object.
>         return super().import_data(*args, **kwargs)
>
>     def skip_row(self, instance, original):
>         # You can access the current logged-in user by `self.user`
>         # and later, do some logical operations
>         # and at last, return either `True` or `False`
>         pass
> ```

You must update the **`skip_row(...)`** method to get the desired result.