# django-import-export how to skip import some rows based on current user login?

Tags: python-3.x, django, csv

Actually started using django-import-export latest version.
Wanted to know where exactly we can override to skip certain rows of the csv from being imported based on current user or the domains from a list of domains he can import data from the csv. How exactly to customize which of the methods to override and how?

In my ModelResource, I have created the list of domains for the current user, and which method of the import-export do I check this and skip the rows from being imported?

class MailboxResource(resources.ModelResource):
mdomain_list = []

```
def import_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # make changes to csv
    super(MailboxResource, self).before_import(*args, **kwargs)
    muser_id = kwargs['user'].id
    muser = kwargs['user']

    # import for all domains
    if muser.is_superuser:
        pass
    # import for domains belonging to the hierarchy
    elif muser is not None:
        exist = muser.groups.filter(name='customers').exists() 
        self.mdomain_list.append(Domain.objects.filter(
            customer__in=Customer.objects.filter(
                        email=muser)))

def skip_row(self, instance, original):
    mdomain = instance.email.partition('@')[2]
    for x in self.mdomain_list:
        print(type(x[0].domain), 'xxx', x[0].domain, mdomain)
        if x[0].domain == mdomain:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Hence customer should be able to import data from the CSV only for domains that belong to him and skip all other rows from the CSV, which don't exist in the list.
CSV:

```
id,name,email,domain,
1,ABC pvt.ltd,abc@zinn.com,zinn.com,
2,XTD,xtd@ggg.com,ggg.co.in,
3,RTG,tiger@goa.com,goa.com
```

If customer doesn't own ggg.com domain, only 1st and 3rd row should get added to the table via import. How can this be achieved?

Using python 3.

Checked the document here: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.skip_row but couldn't make out much for my use-case.

Comment: you can't use this interface without hacky stuffs like thread-local request objects, because this interface only provides the model instance and the row. No arbitrary data is passed to it, so you can't actually get the current request and/or user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**`skip_row(...)`**--(Doc)](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.skip_row) method, as you mentioned.

But, the ***`skip_row(...)`*** method doesn't provide any hooks to the `request.user`, so, we are doing a *simple hack* to get the requested user in `skip_row()` by overriding the  ***`import_data(...)`***

```
from import_export.resources import ModelResource


class BookResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def import_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.get("user") # Here, we are assigning the requested user to the `ModelResource` object.
        return super().import_data(*args, **kwargs)

    def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        # You can access the current logged-in user by `self.user`
        # and later, do some logical operations
        # and at last, return either `True` or `False`
        pass
```

### Upate 1

I have updated the **`skip_row(...)`** method to test whether the skip is working properly or not.

```
class BookResource(ModelResource):
    count = 1

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def import_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.get("user")
        return super().import_data(*args, **kwargs)

    def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        skip = self.count % 2 == 0
        self.count += 1
        return skip
```

[image: preview]

Comment: have taken the user from here already , but what is skip_row is always skipping all the records, I have tried returning  True/ False but it does for the entire recordset and not just the required row. Added my code changes above which I tried. Don't know how exactly to implement. Please guide

Comment: @user956424 to me, the ***`skip_row(...)`*** is working as expected, with the [official example](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) Check the Update-1 section

Comment: Even if one of the domain exists in the self.domain_list, if that row needs to imported and remaining skipped, it just skips all the rows including the one which needs to be imported too. I have checked several times

Comment: I am pretty damn sure the logic inside the *"your"* `skip_row()` method is not working *as you expected*. But, the fact is that the `skip_row()` will work as-is. Check out my updated proof. @user956424

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. I was comparing the queryset object with the string, which required an index value. It works now. Thanks!